# Have all database queries within a request of a controller go to a different database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

My company is nearing the end of a large migration/upgrade from our Rails 2.x app to Rails 4. Yes, I'm aware that of the time of this writing, Rails 4 is in RC and not final, but our goal is to be ready as soon as 4.0 final drops. We've gone through the entire upgrade process, replacing and upgrading gems as necessary, but finally hit a very large brick wall.

*Some quick background:*

- We use unicorn to serve up our app
- We have two PostgreSQL databases, each on different servers. One is a master, the other is a hot replicating read-only standby. Two controllers in our app serve up reports from our data. These reports are commonly very SQL intensive so we have the seamless database pool gem have all queries within those controller actions go through the PostgreSQL standby read-only box.

Unfortunately seamless database pool is not yet updated to work with Rails 4. We've looked into octopus and various other gems with no luck. I recently just thought of this idea of how to handle this issue by forgetting about using a gem and just switch the connection on the request for those specific controllers and then making sure that the connection is switched back to the other database after the request did its business so future requests to that unicorn worker will default to the primary database.

I would like to know if this is a really really bad idea and if anyone else has a better suggestion.

**database.yml:**

```
production:
  host: primary_db_host_ip
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_production
  pool: 5
  username: ****
  password: ****

standby_by:
  host: standby_db_host_ip
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_production
  pool: 5
  username: ****
  password: ****
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  ...

  private

  def switch_db
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("standby_db")
    yield
  ensure
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("production")
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/special_controller.rb:**

```
class SpecialController < ApplicationController
  around_action :switch_db
  ...
  ...
end
```

**UPDATE:** Specifically this is the error that's happening with seamless_database_pool for those that asked how would know if it's not Rails 4 ready...

```
undefined method `reset_transaction' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:336:in `proxy_connection_method'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:122:in `block in reset_transaction'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:243:in `use_master_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:121:in `reset_transaction'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:232:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:90:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:152:in `initialize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:48:in `new'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/seamless_database_pool-1.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/seamless_database_pool_adapter.rb:48:in `seamless_database_pool_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
config/unicorn.rb:16:in `block in reload'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:495:in `call'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:495:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@theapp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: i think that if you have been using seamless_database_pool with success, why not fork the repo and contribute rails4 support. this will not only help yourself but everybody that will need such a thing. opensource, you know?

Comment: What is wrong with seamless_database_pool and Rails4? I don't see any issues open for the gem, and don't see anything preventing Rails4 use

Comment: @phoet That would be fine if we didn't want to get the app up and running as soon as possible. That also assumes that my team already has a working knowledge of the seamless_database_pool gem to even start trying to fix it. I mean, isn't that part of the point of gems and libraries? Install them and use them without having to worry about how they work.

Comment: @t27duck actually that is not the way it's supposed to be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, one of the other developers is going to try to dig into the gem and see if he can get it working in Rails 4. Hopefully it won't take too long...